# How to show a loading indicator until all async http calls are completed - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asynchronous, dynamic

My question is how to show a loading spinner until all of my async http requests are completed. This way I wouldn't show bits and pieces of the screen until all of the data is received from the server.

My biggest issue is that I have components that are triggered specifically through the html, so I can't simply put an `*ngIf` statement over part of the html when I want to show it.

Here's what I have so far. FYI, the Template variable that currently triggers the visibility of the html is set when one of the http requests complete in this component. I want to wait for the child component's http requests to complete before showing the html, but I must execute the logic in the html in order to call the child components.

The `*ngIf` statement does **NOT** currently work in the way I desire, I'm just showing what I'm currently doing.

```
<div class="col-sm-12"
            *ngIf="Template">
    <div id="nav" style="height: 200px">
        <div id="outer"
             style="width: 100%">
            <div id="inner">
                <o-grid>
                </o-grid>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <collapsible-panel *ngFor="let s of Template?.s; let i = index"
                       [title]="s.header">
        <div *ngFor="let c of s.c">
            <fact [eC]="c.c"
                    [label]="c.l">
            </fact>
        </div>
    </collapsible-panel>

    <collapsible-panel title="T">
        <div>
            <i-f >
            </i-f>
        </div>
    </collapsible-panel>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!Template" class="spinner"></div>
```

---

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**: Here's the solution I implemented, per the answer below from @danday74.

I instantiated the variable inside of my service where I make all of my http requests. I defined it as true to start, and set it to false in one of the child components when the subscribe completes.

I'll just need to make sure in the future to set `cService.asyncRequestsInProgress` to false wherever the last async http request takes place, if it ever changes.

Parent HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12"
             [ngClass]="{hideMe:cService.asyncRequestsInProgress}">
    ......
</div>
<div *ngIf="cService.asyncRequestsInProgress" class="spinner"></div>
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CService {

    asyncRequestsInProgress: boolean = true;
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Child Component (Where the last async request completes):

```
export class FComponent implements OnInit {
    ....
    doSomething() {
        this.cService.getWhatever().subscribe(x => {
            this.cService.asyncRequestsInProgress = false;
        }
    }
}
```

styles.css

```
.hideMe {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I am confused about the *ngIf piece, you mention that you cannot simply use this, but your example shows an *ngIf. One thought would be to move the Template variable into a service as public, so that the parent could set it to true when the logic begins, then the child could set it to false when the logic completes. If your goal is not to use *ngIf I may need clarification on this part.

Comment: @Marshal, this is my current code, I can take it out for clarification. I included it in the code to demonstrate what isn't currently working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a resolver. A resolver ensures data is loaded before the component loads.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use *ngIf you could just use `[ngClass]="{hideMe: allAsyncRequestsComplete}"` to style the bit you don't want to show until loading is complete. CSS might be:

```
.hideMe {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And set `allAsyncRequestsComplete` to true when loading is done.

Comment: Would the use of a resolver work if I have async calls that are dependent on data from other async calls? I would need to execute some logic in the child components, which make some async calls that are dependent on other async calls, in order to correctly call all of my endpoints.

Comment: I ended up using your second option with the css styling. Reason being, I have async calls that depend on the result from other async calls. I felt as if the resolver would have been too much work this far into my project. My understanding of the resolver is that you essentially can put all of your async calls into a resolver and with my example, it would require some of the logic to go in as well. I will keep this approach in mind going forward with future projects though! Thanks for the insight and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolvers for the loading, then in app.component.ts, set your variable to true or false depending on the event:

```
navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    //true
  }
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    //false
  }

  // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
  if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    //false
  }
  if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
    //false
  }
}
```